# Reduce Query Syntax for ends_with()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, query

I have the following query:

`--query "Contents[?ends_with(Key, 'jpg') || ends_with(Key, 'NEF') || ends_with(Key, 'nef') || ends_with(Key, 'CR2') || ends_with(Key, 'cr2')]"`

Is there a way to reduce this? I tried with all of the suffixes in one ends_with separated by ORs. That didn't work. The above works, but it's sloppy. Thanks!